# How to migrate data from Parse.com to Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have two production apps that are currently using Parse.com. I have no plans on using Parse server, and I wanted to switch to the firebase service. I was wondering if there was a way to migrate my database from Parse.com to Firebase

Comment: Dan, I am planing to create a set of videos that guide step by step how to host Parse Server on your own server in Amazon cloud. If you are interested, please find a few seconds to watch this video which explains a little bit about this initiative https://youtu.be/flgtkzzpAzo

Comment: I wrote a blog post about that: 
http://bettysteger.com/migrating-users-from-parse-to-firebase

Comment: Hi, did you migrate from Parse? Which service did you use. If it's firebase, how did you manage to migrate your data. I'm facing same issue now days. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution? I need to migrate my push users from Parse to Firebase.

Comment: I recently came across a [migration strategy](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-android) from the Firebase website. This may help someone.

Answer (score 6):

There are differences between Parse and Firebase that makes a straight migration not as easy as you would hope.

Parse is based on a relational database, where as Firebase stores all it's data in JSON - thus a "copy and paste" job isn't going to work here.

On top of that the way that the two platforms organise user authentication is completely different.

So unfortunately no easy solution here.

Comment: You crazy... Parse uses MongoDB which is not a relational DB.

Comment: Correct @FelipeCaldas - However Parse acts like a relational database of table and rows. The user does't see whats going under the hood in terms of how MongoDB works.

Comment: Well, I'll agree to that! @dylan buckley

Comment: I wrote a blog post about that: http://bettysteger.com/migrating-users-from-parse-to-firebase

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a import JSON option so if you get your data out of Parse.com as JSON, it can be imported.

However, the structure Parse uses to create relationships between data is (probably) going to be different than Firebase, so it's going to take some planning and coding to make the transition.

Once we had a plan, we found it easiest to just craft an importer App that would take the Parse.com data structure, and massage it to a Firebase format that worked for our app.

In some cases we had to start from scratch as the thought process is different from Parse (objects) to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase API is completely different from the Parse one. It means that you have to learn other API, SDKs, etc, and rewrite your frontend code.

Does not exist an easy path to migrate from Parse to Firebase.

Moreover I think it is not a good decision. Parse Server community is growing and it is becoming even better than original Parse. In a short time, Parse Server will become the best framework for backend and API development.

My recommendation to you is to migrate to a Parse Hosting provider. Using this kind of solution you will use same Parse APIs and features. It will not require you learn other technology nor rewrite any frontend code.

You can find some options in parse server repository:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#parse-server-sample-application

For a full disclaimer, I am co-founder of https://www.back4app.com that is the first parse server mover.

Comment: It is a good decision to leave Parse. Cheaper, faster and I expect google to maintain the project longer than 3rd party Parse providers. Yes the transformation is a hassle. To migrate to a 3rd Party is also problematic with Parse. So why not to invest a little more work and move to google other than being lazy? Then the 3rd Party bankrupts, decides to cut operation and I can start the whole migration again. No thanks.

Comment: Take a look in the link how many applications Google has already shutdown: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_products#Discontinued_products_and_services You are not safe because Firebase belongs to Google. And if Google shutdown it, you will have to migrate again. The big thing of Parse Server is: open source and no vendor lock-in. You always have access to your database and at anytime you can easily move it to anywhere you want and run your own Parse Server instance. If any Parse Sever provider discontinue, it will be pretty simple to run in another provider.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am that type of guy to not make the same mistake twice. I see far less chance that google kills Firebase than your start-up bankrupts I am sorry. I prefer not to migrate again and again. But we became off-topic. All of us may share different view on the topic.