# Migrate parse installation object to firebase

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, migration

I have an app which uses Parse and I want to migrate it to Firebase. I was extended the parse installation objects to send customized push notifications. I'm wondering if I can migrate these parse installation objects to Firebase and use it from Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cookie cutter click-though way to import an app that uses Parse.com into Firebase. The products are too different for that.

There are however migration guides for developers looking to migrate their iOS and Android apps on the Firebase site: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/#migrating_from_parse

There is also a repo with parse-migration-tools from Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/parse-migration-tools

Finally have a look at this question, where experienced developers chimed in already: [How to migrate data from Parse.com to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185483/how-to-migrate-data-from-parse-com-to-firebase)

Comment: Yeah I know this documentation and github repo so it is not possible to use my old parse installation object data from Firebase am I right? (I was using parse for just push notifications and want to use Firebase too) I have to populate my data in Firebase in order to send customized push notifications for my audience groups.

Comment: There is indeed no support yet for migrating installation IDs. It's the third checkbox in: https://github.com/firebase/parse-migration-tools#parse-migration-tools

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. I have the device tokens for ios and device ids for android on my seperate mysql server. Can I use them in Firebase to create audience? @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer: Former lead of Parse Push. Author of parse-migration-tools]

I'm a bit nervous that you're out of luck if you're referring to "installation Ids". Firebase supports iOS and Android. Android devices aren't going to be easy to port for a few reasons, though iOS can be done without too much work. Let's break it down by the push backend:

1. Most people who talk about "installation Ids" are talking about Parse's self-hosted push network (PPNS or Parse Push Notification Service). This is hosted at push.parse.com and will go away in January. There's nothing anyone can do to keep those devices connected. As an FYI you'll also realy want to update your apps to disable PPNS because it will likely drain your customers' battery when they have a background service repeatedly trying to connect to a URI that isn't going to exist anymore.
2. If you're using GCM directly, you're still out of luck actually. Parse [uses a version of GCM that's too old](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1369) to work with Firebase. [I tried to help fix it](https://github.com/FirebasePrivate/Parse-SDK-Android/commit/632632740a4878a24e40f0aaeca13c6d5ee2dc6c), but we weren't able to upgrade to GCM v4 and [keep the Parse design style](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/445). The new Firebase SDK makes it possible to fix the issue and keep the Parse design requirements, but I'm far too overextended to build this right now. If someone wants to grab a shovel, I'd be glad to explain the right design.
3. iOS will actually work. I intended to make this turnkey in parse-migration-tools but won't have time until the end of the year. Firebase Cloud Messaging has a [batchImport](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens) API for importing iOS tokens. I also wrote support for [batchImport in parse-migration-tools](https://github.com/firebase/parse-migration-tools/pull/1) to help you import your devices (and other data) faster. If I were migrating Parse Push from iOS, I would personally write a migration and bulkImport function that used [batchImport](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens) to create GCM tokens and [subscribed Parse Channels as FCM topics](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance) (note the batchAdd method; it may help you more efficiently do your initial import).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#import_existing_user_apns_tokens

You can just importat all of the existing users device id's and FireBase will generate unique id's for them.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking 4